# c++ ofstream(someVariable) initialization

Tags: c++

So I tried to do this:

```
#include <iostream>//For cout/cin
#include <fstream> //For ifstream/ofstream

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string types[] = {"Creativity", "Action", "Service"};
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(types)/sizeof(string); i++) {
        string type = types[i];
        string filename = type + ".html";
        ofstream newFile(filename);
        //newFile << toHTML(getActivities(type));
        newFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm being hit with errors. I'm new to C++, so I don't know what to try, or if this is even possible (SURELY it is...).
I tried the following, but it was really just a stab in the dark and didn't help:

```
#include <iostream>//For cout/cin
#include <fstream> //For ifstream/ofstream

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string types[] = {"Creativity", "Action", "Service"};
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(types)/sizeof(string); i++) {
        string type = types[i];
        //Attempting to add const..
        const string filename = type + ".html";
        ofstream newFile(filename);
        //newFile << toHTML(getActivities(type));
        newFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I mean, its all happy if I do `ofstream newFile("somefile.html");

Comment: My guess is that you're using C++03, and thus have no constructor that works with a `std::string`, just one that works with the C-style string you get from `c_str()`.

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: You’ve posted the same code twice …

Comment: @KonradRudolph - no, the second is **slightly** different from the first. And not just in the comments. <g>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original IOstream library didn't have a constructor taking a `std::string`. The only type supported was `char const*`. You can get a `char const*` from a `std::string` using `c_str()`:

```
std::string name("whatever");
std::ofstream out(name.c_str());
```

The type of a string literal isn't of type `std::string` but it is of type `char const[n]` where `n` is the number of characters in the string, including the terminating null character.

In C++ 2011 the File stream classes are improved to also take `std::string` where a string is expected.